# jQuery getJSON not populating html table

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am working with the following example from the internet, to get up to speed with populating a table with data from JSON using AJAX, but I just can’t get the table to populate. The headings come up, but there is no data. It must be something obvious, but I just can’t see it. I have validated the simple JSON and included the latest versions of jQuery and Bootstrap. The employee.json file is in the same folder as index.html. I would be very grateful if someone could point out where I have gone wrong.

Comment: You need to include code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It might also be wise to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: What following example? Where is the code?